# How to setup value of another filed based on one filed value in Django Python

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, relationship

I have two model Stock and Trade.

```
 class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, editable=True)


class Trade(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, editable=False, )
    name = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, related_name='stock_name')
    trade_choice = [
        (1, 'BUY'),
        (0, 'SELL')
    ]
    type = models.CharField(choices=trade_choice, default='BUY', max_length=5)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, )
    price = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stock_price')
```

The problem with Trade.price as foreign key is that, when user select Trade.name as "APPLE" to buy the price will not be of APPLE instead it will be price value of all stock from which user can choose which is wrong. I want to set value of price depending on user stock name for buy or sell.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

class Trade(models.Model):
stock_model_obj = models.IntegerField(blank=False, editable=True)

and then you can easily all fields of stock obj easily.

let's say instance is obj of Trade model then you can directly use instance.stock_model_obj.price or instance.stock_model_obj.whatever_field_of_Stock

P.S. You can also use further joins if stock model have other foreign keys

Happy coding

Comment: How this is stock model object stock_model_obj = models.IntegerField(blank=False, editable=True) ? We are not specifying anything related to Stock model while creating stock_model_obj.